# NavigationDrawer's menu is not working

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

When I click at the menu items, then layouts not coming to view.

And MainActicity wanna "menu1_Fragment.java" encode with "android.support.v4.app.Fragment"

İf I encode only "Fragment", MainActivity is getting error.

> In compatible types.
>
> Required :android.support.v4.app.Fragment
>
> Found :intizamyazilim.navigationdrawernew.menu1_Fragment

**Here is menu1_Fragment.java**

```
package intizamyazilim.navigationdrawernew;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by Administrator on 01.03.2015.
 */
public class menu1_Fragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    View  rootview;

    @Nullable

    //  @Override
    public View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu1_layout, container, false);
        return rootview;
    }
}
```

Comment: "MainActivity is getting error" What error, specifically?

Comment: Look at my question again. I update this.

Answer (score 0):

I Fix it.

I changed this "menu1_Fragment.java" with this codes:

```
package intizamyazilim.navigationdrawernew;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class menu1_Fragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    public menu1_Fragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu1_layout, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No it is not the proper way to fix it. The proble here is that you are extending your menu1_Fragment using support library and on the other hand you are importing fragment from SDK(import android.app.Fragment;). Make it consistent. Either use fragment from support or from android SDK.

Comment: No. it's a gray line.

`import android.app.Fragment;`